# GC_CONCURRENT running non-stop

Tags: java, android, performance, garbage-collection

I see the following in my cmd window when using `adb logcat`
[image: GC_CONCURRENT_logcat]

Is this indicative of a memory leak? My assumption is that java garbage collection is running continuously, but I'm not sure. Any clarification is welcome!

Answer (score 1):

> Is this indicative of a memory leak?

The best test is to see how much memory is used after a GC.  As you can see it starts at 36% and finishes at 36% so if there is a leak it is pretty small.

More likely you are;

- allocating too fast
- not using enough heap
- not GCing as much as you think.  i.e. do you know this is a problem?

Comment: Can you further explain each of those bullets? For the third, im not explicitly calling System.gc()...